# Jmeter protocol error?

Tags: jmeter

This is my first question. I've read other responses about uploading scenarios, but I cannot find a solution.

When I try to open an "upload file" window:

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 51: `http://xxxxxxxxxx/upload_file_window.ud121?vds={%22oid%22:0,%22folder%22:0,%22section%22:%22myfiles%22,%22last_section%22:%22videos%22,%22uploaded%22:false,%22uploader%22:null,%22searchresults%22:[],%22plupload_settings%22:{%22upload_url%22:%22upload_file_final.ud121%22,%22filters%22:[{%22title%22:%22Image%20files%22,%22extensions%22:%22jpg,gif,png,jpeg,JPG,GIF,PNG,JPEG%22},{%22title%22:%22Audio%20files%22,%22extensions%22:%22mp3,wmaupload,m4a,wav%22},{%22title%22:%22Video%20files%22,%22extensions%22:%22mpg,mpeg,wmv,flv,mov,swf,mp4,f4v%22}],%22file_size_limit%22:%222048mb%22},%22new_playlist_x%22:1280,%22new_playlist_y%22:720}`

```
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3092)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:936)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:234)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:211)
```

It's a jmeter protocol error? (I see something recorded in ajax in jmeter).
How could I see the HTTP request for the upload? Firebug?
Wher should be the files for uploading in local?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the file to upload in /bin.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

> Uploading files
>   Some browsers (e.g. Firefox and Opera) don't include the full name of a file when uploading files. This can cause the JMeter proxy server to fail. One solution is to ensure that any files to be uploaded are in the JMeter working directory, either by copying the files there or by starting JMeter in the directory containing the files.

Comment: OK thanks, but that is the final part of my question.
At first, I need to record the upload request and through JMeter proxy I can't.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use HTTP GET method for file upload. I believe that it should be POST or PUT.
2. Even if your application supports it your whole request size will be limited to something like 2 kilobytes
3. No matter where files live, it's better to provide full path for anything external: files to upload, CSV Data Set files, etc.
4. You can record file upload but JMeter isn't smart enough to pick up file's full path, it has to be in JMeter's working directory (usually /bin folder of your JMeter installation but it may be different i.e. in case if you start JMeter via desktop shortcut)
5. See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) post for more information and step-by-step guidelines.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri,
The GET request for upload was recorded by blazemeter's chrome extension. I'm not sure if the application under test allows post for upload action... Could you give me any tip to convert the request in POST?

Comment: Changing request type is as simple as choosing "POST" from "Method" dropdown. I'm pretty sure that file needs to be uploaded via method other than "GET"